# webpack.config.js file errors in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-5

I am having my angular project inside a java application inside webpages->ressources->static-> angular project
Following is my webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = (envOptions) => {
    envOptions = envOptions || {};
    const config = {
        entry: {
            main: './src/main.ts'
        },
        output: {
            path: '/dist',
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: 'main.js'
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            ],
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.html']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
                
                { test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'style-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|pdf)$/,
                    type: 'assets/',
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/test.pdf',
                    generator: {
                        filename: './[name][ext]',
                    },
                }
            ]
        },
    };
    if (envOptions.MODE === 'prod') {
        config.plugins = [
            /*new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'styles.css', disable: false, allChunks: true }),*/
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                beautify: false,
                mangle: {
                    screw_ie8: true,
                    keep_fnames: true
                },
                compress: {
                    screw_ie8: true,
                    warnings: false,
                    conditionals: true,
                    unused: true,
                    comparisons: true,
                    sequences: true,
                    dead_code: true,
                    evaluate: true,
                    if_return: true,
                    join_vars: true,
                    negate_iife: false // we need this for lazy v8
                },
                comments: false
            }),
           new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin( /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(@angular|esm5)/, path.resolve(__dirname, './src') ),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                title: 'Dashboard',
              //  template: 'index.ejs', // Load a custom template (ejs by default see the FAQ for details) 
                inject: 'body'
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                $: 'jquery',
                jquery: 'jquery'
            })
        ];
    }
    return config;
};
```

This is my project folder structure

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base build/ -w",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.js -w ",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build:dev",
    "lint": "tslint ./**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.2.0",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.10.378",
    "bootbox": "^5.5.3",
    "core-js": "^3.25.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.1",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^11.0.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.16.105",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.8",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~14.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^14.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "~18.7.15",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

When I'm building the file, I'm getting the following errors

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Compiling RuleSet failed: Query arguments on 'loader' has been removed in favor of the 'options' property (at ruleSet[1].rules[2].loader: file-loader?name=assets/test.pdf)
    at RuleSetCompiler.error (projectFolder\src\main\webapp\resources\static\node_modules\webpack\lib\rules\RuleSetCompiler.js:373:10)
    at projectFolder\src\main\webapp\resources\static\node_modules\webpack\lib\rules\UseEffectRulePlugin.js:160:29
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (projectFolder\src\main\webapp\resources\static\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:49:1)
    at RuleSetCompiler.compileRule (projectFolder\main\webapp\resources\static\node_modules\webpack\lib\rules\RuleSetCompiler.js:177:19)
    at projectFolder\src\main\webapp\resources\static\node_modules\webpack\lib\rules\RuleSetCompiler.js:154:9
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at RuleSetCompiler.compileRules (projectFolder\src\main\webapp\resources\static\node_modules\webpack\lib\rules\RuleSetCompiler.js:153:16)
    at RuleSetCompiler.compileRule (projectFolder\src\main\webapp\resources\static\node_modules\webpack\lib\rules\RuleSetCompiler.js:184:30)
    at projectFolder\src\main\webapp\resources\static\node_modules\webpack\lib\rules\RuleSetCompiler.js:154:9
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I'm unable to find the root cause. I tried many solutions and all the fixes are throwing a new error. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have added a file-loader to load the tsconfig.json file using awesome-typescript-loader, the library wasn't importing as it has compatibility issues with typescript version. I used --force to install & following is the error.

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist/entry.js):
TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function
    at setupWatchRun (projectFolder\src\main\webapp\resources\static\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\instance.ts:365:14)
```

Updated package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.2.0",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.10.378",
    "bootbox": "^5.5.3",
    "core-js": "^3.25.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.1",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^11.0.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.16.105",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.6",
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.8",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~14.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^14.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "~18.7.15",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
```

Updated webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
//var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = (envOptions) => {
    envOptions = envOptions || {};
    const config = {
        entry: {
            main: './src/main.ts'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: '[name].bundle.js'
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            ],
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.html'],
              alias: {
                src: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/'),
            },
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader'},
                { test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: [
                         {
                            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                            options: { configFileName: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json') }
                        },
                            'angular2-template-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'style-loader',
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|pdf|otf|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 1000000,
                                name: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
    };
    if (envOptions.MODE === 'prod') {
        config.plugins = [
            /*new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'styles.css', disable: false, allChunks: true }),*/
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                beautify: false,
                mangle: {
                    screw_ie8: true,
                    keep_fnames: true
                },
                compress: {
                    screw_ie8: true,
                    warnings: false,
                    conditionals: true,
                    unused: true,
                    comparisons: true,
                    sequences: true,
                    dead_code: true,
                    evaluate: true,
                    if_return: true,
                    join_vars: true,
                    negate_iife: false // we need this for lazy v8
                },
                comments: false
            }),
//            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
//                /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)@angular/,
//                __dirname
//            ),
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(@angular|esm5)/, path.resolve(__dirname, './src')),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                title: 'Dashboard',
                //  template: 'index.ejs', // Load a custom template (ejs by default see the FAQ for details) 
                inject: 'body'
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                $: 'jquery',
                jquery: 'jquery'
            })
        ];
    }
    return config;
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Query arguments on 'loader' has been removed in favor of the 'options' property`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Compiling RuleSet failed: Query arguments on 'loader' has been removed in favor of the 'options' property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356793/error-compiling-ruleset-failed-query-arguments-on-loader-has-been-removed-in)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski no, it is now throwing a diff error I have already added a loader, below is the error


ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts 11:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (11:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
|
> @NgModule({
|   declarations: [
|     AppComponent,
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-45 11:41-50

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/what-does-the-mean-inside-an-import-path

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I have made the changes as suggested in the above link, still the same error