# Compiling RuleSet failed in Vue 2 Project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, package.json

I initiated a vue 2 project and it worked well. After that, I have installed some dependencies and tried to build it again using **npm run serve**. Then there is an error in the terminal as in below.

```
Compiling RuleSet failed: Evaluation of condition function threw error (at clonedRuleSet-40.exclude[0]: filepath => {
                    // always transpile js in vue files
                    if (/\.vue\.jsx?$/.test(filepath)) {
                      return false
                    }
                    // exclude dynamic entries from cli-service
                    if (filepath.startsWith(cliServicePath)) {
                      return true
                    }
                    // check if this is something the user explicitly wants to transpile
                    if (options.transpileDependencies.some(dep => filepath.match(dep))) {
                      return false
                    }
                    // Don't transpile node_modules
                    return /node_modules/.test(filepath)
                  })
```

This is the package.json file in my project.

```
{
  "name": "vue2_project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "^0.3.0",
    "@coreui/vue": "^3.2.12",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.7",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.2.0",
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.5",
    "css-vars-ponyfill": "^1.9.0",
    "epic-spinners": "^1.0.3",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "qrcode.vue": "^1.7.0",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-bootstrap-typeahead": "^0.2.6",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-chartjs-typescript": "^3.3.3",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-clipboards": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-gtag": "^1.16.1",
    "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.13",
    "vue-password-strength-meter": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.4",
    "vue-tabs-component": "^1.5.0",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.4",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@types/vue2-editor": "^2.6.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Before installed these packages, the project was build successfully. How can I solve this issue to build the project well?

Comment: This is a problem with the vue-loader. If I were you, I would not add all the packages at once. I would run the command after adding each package to address the exact mismatched package. Also see: https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/2613 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475134/webpack-cli-error-compiling-ruleset-failed

Comment: @Raeisi After installed these packages successfully and tried to build a project, there are some errors called **ERROR  ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

        options should NOT have additional properties
        options should NOT have additional properties
        options should NOT have additional properties
        options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
        options should match exactly one schema in oneOf**

Comment: Could be related to ESLInt. Try to remove it and check if you can serve the project without it.